# using UCAR IOSP to read a dataset

Tags: java, netcdf

I am new to Java, sorry. Or rather, returning to it after a long while.

I am trying to use a UCAR Java package. There is a .OIS file supported by the UCAR as one of the iosp examples. When I run the following code, it complains that the file was "Not a valid CDM file". But I can assure you it is as it comes from the direct website of the data provider... does anyone know how to use this package? I would guess one needs to "register" the IOSP, but if its compiled I'm not sure why the netCDF doesn't know to use it. If anyone has any experience with this package it'd be greatly appreciated.

Sample data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri24oz6h1rxl7on/F12199501290001.OIS?dl=0

```
    package processOISexample;
import ucar.nc2.NetcdfFile;
import ucar.nc2.iosp.*;
import ucar.*;
import java.io.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        // Identify the files to run

         String s="C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/sampledata/F12199501290001.OIS";

         try {

              NetcdfFile ncfile1 = NetcdfFile.open(s);

              ncfile1.close(); 
         } finally {

         }





    }

}
```

Comment: A link to the actual data source would be helpful for debugging would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a shortcoming in the IOSP code (not handling a header line "start direction"). Can you open an issue (including a zipped version of the data file) at http://github.com/Unidata/thredds/issues ?

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Thank you so much. Do you know if it would be easy to fix, or if there is an easy work around? I need to get moving on this.